# Finding pairs from a single column depending on second column from the same table

Tags: sql, db2, recursive-query, self-join

I have the below scenario

Source Table:

```
Col1 Col2 Time  
I1   CRR   T0  
I1   CRH   T1  
I1   CRH   T2  
I1   CRR   T3  
I1   CRH   T4  
I1   CRR   T5  
I1   CRH   T6  
I2   CRH   T7  
I2   CRR   T8
```

The value pair here is (CRH,CRR) - CRH is the starting event and CRR is the end event.
I need to get rid of all the end events before the corresponding starting events (this is decided based on time column) and also capture the valid starting event and ending event pair. If there are multiple start events before an end event then need to pick the earliest to establish the pair. Here is the desired result

```
Col1 Col2 Time Col3 Col4  
I1   CRH   T1  CRR   T3  
I1   CRH   T4  CRR   T5  
I1   CRH   T6   -    -  (since no corresponding end event - this is fine)  
I2   CRH   T7  CRR   T8
```

I am using DB2 any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a more recent version of db2, then you have the `lag()` and `lead()` functions.

If so, try this:

```
select col1, col2, time, nextcol2, nexttime
from (select t.*,
             lead(col2) over (partition by col1 order by time) as nextcol2
             lead(time) over (partition by col1 order by time) as nexttime
      from t
     ) t
where not(col2 = 'CRR' and nextcol2 = 'CRH')
```

If you don't have the `lead()` function, you can do something similar with a correlated subquery.

The comment greatly clarifies what you want.  You are looking for the next end after a given start.  For that, I use a correlated subquery to get the next time.  Here is the structure of the query:

```
select t.*, tend.col2, tend.time
from (select t.*,
             (select MIN(time) from t t2 where t.col1 = t2.col1 and t2.time > t.time and t2.col2 = 'CRR'
             ) endtime
      from t
      where col2 = 'CRH'
     ) t left outer join
     t tend
     on t.col1 = tend.col1 and t.time = tend.endtime
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply...but the query you posted is combining the leading row with the current row, my requirement is to get the very first starting event and then the matching ending event, something like this 'I1   CRH   T1  CRR   T3' instead of 'I1   CRH   T1  CRH   T2'. Please let me know if this is not clear...thanks again!

Comment: @MdMuqeetAli . . . That makes more sense, actually.  See the revised answer.

Comment: thanks a ton!....Works perfectly....just selected the top most row for every end event ....here's the updated query........select * from (
select t.*, tend.col2, tend.time, 
row_number() over(partition by tend.col2,t.time order by tend.time) row_num
from (select t.*,
             (select MIN(time) from t t2 where t.col1 = t2.col1 and t2.time > t.time and t2.col2 = 'CRR'
             ) endtime
      from t
      where col2 = 'CRH'
     ) tend left outer join
     t
     on t.col1 = tend.col1 and t.time = tend.endtime
)
where row_num = 1

Comment: Do you think this is the best way we could do it or it can be done using the recursive query?

Comment: @MdMuqeetAli . . . I prefer this approach.  I haven't done recursive queries in DB2, so I don't know if it would perform as well.